# Error de diseño en Bootstrap File Input

Tags: html, bootstrap

Hola necesito saber xq mi diseño se descuadra, mi imput con los button estoy utilizando:

boostrap 3.3.7

```
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                  rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>plugins/bootstrap-input/fileinput.min.css">

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>plugins/bootstrap-input/fileinput.js"></script>


<div class="modal fade" id="modal_subir_excel_producto"
         role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title-ep">Subir Excel de Productos</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body form">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <form action="<?php echo base_url('plaza/carga_masiva') ?>" method="post" 
                                  enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                                <div id="form_derivacion" class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                    <label class="control-label">Ingrese el archivo excel a cargar,
                                        descargue la plantilla <a id="ref_plazas" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Plantilla/MASIVO_PLAZAS.xls" download>aqui.</a>
                                        <br><code>NOTA: Debe respetar los formatos que se mencionan en los comentarios de la plantilla.</code>
                                    </label><br>
                                    <input class="file" type="file" id="upload" name="upload"/>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <span style="color: red" id="mensajeError"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Exactamente cuál plugin estás utilizando? ¿Es este: http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo ?

Comment: @KroneauxSchneider exacto eso es la actualmente uso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando el plugin [**File Input de Krajee**](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input), comprueba las clases de los botones como se menciona en su [documentación sobre la configuración](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#options); esto lo haces desde el Javascript del `fileinput`:

```
$("#").fileinput({
    ...
    browseClass: "btn btn-primary btn-sm", // "btn-sm" hace al botón más pequeño
    browseLabel: "Selecciona archivos",
    browseIcon: "<i class=\"fa fa-file\"></i> ", // Personalmente me gusta más FA
    removeClass: "btn btn-danger btn-sm", // El color lo defines como a cualquier "btn"
    removeLabel: "Borrar",
    removeIcon: "<i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i> ",
    uploadClass: "btn btn-default btn-xs", // También puedes probar con "btn-xs"
    uploadLabel: "Subir",
    uploadIcon: "<i class=\"fa fa-upload\"></i> ",
    ...
})
```